# Build boost with MinGW on github actions

Tags: windows, github, boost, continuous-deployment, github-actions

I'm unable to install boost on github actions (on windows-latest). Here i download .zip and run bootstrap (this works with no problem):

```bsh
$uri = 'https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.68.0/source/boost_1_68_0.zip'
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -OutFile C:\boost.zip -UserAgent [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent]::Chrome
cd C:\install\boost_1_68_0\tools\build
.\bootstrap.bat gcc (or mingw)
```

And then i install boost, but it fails:

```bsh
cd C:\install\boost_1_68_0\tools\build
.\b2 install --prefix="C:\boost-build" toolset=gcc
$env:Path += ";C:\boost-build\bin"

cd C:\install\boost_1_68_0
& C:\boost-build\bin\b2.exe --build-dir="C:\install\boost_1_68_0\build" --with-system --with-program_options --with-serialization --with-test --build-type=complete -j2 --prefix="C:\boost" toolset=gcc install
```

Some logs:

```
searching for -lmingwex
2020-08-21T15:50:37.6440591Z C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingwex
2020-08-21T15:50:37.6460133Z C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
2020-08-21T15:50:37.6478829Z C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
2020-08-21T15:50:37.6492262Z C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
2020-08-21T15:50:37.6493427Z C:/ProgramData/Chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmsvcrt
2020-08-21T15:50:37.6557648Z collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
2020-08-21T15:50:37.6559763Z 
2020-08-21T15:50:37.6585411Z     "g++"   "-Wl,--out-implib,C:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\system\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi\libboost_system-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll.a" -o "C:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\system\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi\libboost_system-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll" -Wl,-h -Wl,libboost_system-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll -shared -Wl,--start-group "C:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\system\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi\error_code.o"  -Wl,-Bstatic  -Wl,-Bdynamic  -Wl,--end-group -m32 -mthreads -march=i686 
2020-08-21T15:50:39.0837098Z ...skipped <pC:\boost\lib>libboost_timer-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll for lack of <pC:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\timer\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi>libboost_timer-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll...
2020-08-21T15:50:39.0851962Z gcc.compile.c++ C:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\test\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi\execution_monitor.o
2020-08-21T15:50:39.8118085Z gcc.compile.c++ C:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\test\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi\debug.o
2020-08-21T15:50:40.2338237Z ...skipped <pC:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\timer\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi>libboost_timer-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll.a for lack of <pC:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\chrono\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi>libboost_chrono-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll.a...
2020-08-21T15:50:40.2421141Z gcc.compile.c++ C:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\test\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi\cpp_main.o
2020-08-21T15:50:42.3085102Z ...skipped <pC:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\test\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi>libboost_prg_exec_monitor-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll for lack of <pC:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\timer\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi>libboost_timer-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll.a...
2020-08-21T15:50:42.3390490Z ...skipped <pC:\boost\lib>libboost_prg_exec_monitor-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll for lack of <pC:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\test\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi>libboost_prg_exec_monitor-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll...
2020-08-21T15:50:42.3444885Z gcc.compile.c++ C:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\test\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi\decorator.o
2020-08-21T15:51:05.4241487Z gcc.compile.c++ C:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\test\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi\unit_test_parameters.o
2020-08-21T15:51:05.4369569Z ...skipped <pC:\boost\lib>libboost_program_options-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll.a for lack of <pC:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\program_options\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi>libboost_program_options-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll.a...
2020-08-21T15:51:05.4384074Z ...skipped <pC:\boost\lib>libboost_serialization-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll.a for lack of <pC:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\serialization\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi>libboost_serialization-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll.a...
2020-08-21T15:51:05.4385413Z ...skipped <pC:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\serialization\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi>libboost_wserialization-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll.a for lack of <pC:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\serialization\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi>libboost_serialization-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll.a...
2020-08-21T15:51:05.4410211Z ...skipped <pC:\boost\lib>libboost_wserialization-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll.a for lack of <pC:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\serialization\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi>libboost_wserialization-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll.a...
2020-08-21T15:51:05.4467097Z ...skipped <pC:\boost\lib>libboost_system-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll.a for lack of <pC:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\system\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi>libboost_system-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll.a...
2020-08-21T15:51:05.4480197Z ...skipped <pC:\boost\lib>libboost_chrono-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll.a for lack of <pC:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\chrono\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi>libboost_chrono-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll.a...
2020-08-21T15:51:05.4481308Z ...skipped <pC:\boost\lib>libboost_timer-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll.a for lack of <pC:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\timer\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi>libboost_timer-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll.a...
2020-08-21T15:51:05.4482701Z ...skipped <pC:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\test\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi>libboost_prg_exec_monitor-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll.a for lack of <pC:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\timer\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi>libboost_timer-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll.a...
2020-08-21T15:51:05.4562400Z ...skipped <pC:\boost\lib>libboost_prg_exec_monitor-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll.a for lack of <pC:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\test\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\threading-multi>libboost_prg_exec_monitor-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.dll.a...
2020-08-21T15:51:05.4750061Z gcc.archive C:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\system\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\link-static\threading-multi\libboost_system-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.a
2020-08-21T15:51:05.4894206Z common.copy C:\boost\lib\libboost_system-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.a
2020-08-21T15:51:05.4911430Z C:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\system\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\link-static\threading-multi\libboost_system-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.a
2020-08-21T15:51:05.4913574Z         1 file(s) copied.
2020-08-21T15:51:05.5448927Z gcc.archive C:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\chrono\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\link-static\threading-multi\libboost_chrono-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.a
2020-08-21T15:51:05.5612874Z common.copy C:\boost\lib\libboost_chrono-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.a
2020-08-21T15:51:05.5629482Z C:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\chrono\build\gcc-8.1.0\release\address-model-32\link-static\threading-multi\libboost_chrono-mgw81-mt-x32-1_68.a
2020-08-21T15:51:08.7562611Z gcc.archive C:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\test\build\gcc-8.1.0\debug\address-model-32\link-static\threading-multi\libboost_unit_test_framework-mgw81-mt-d-x32-1_68.a
2020-08-21T15:51:08.7845048Z common.copy C:\boost\lib\libboost_unit_test_framework-mgw81-mt-d-x32-1_68.a
2020-08-21T15:51:08.7845690Z C:\install\boost_1_68_0\build\boost\bin.v2\libs\test\build\gcc-8.1.0\debug\address-model-32\link-static\threading-multi\libboost_unit_test_framework-mgw81-mt-d-x32-1_68.a
2020-08-21T15:51:08.7846336Z         1 file(s) copied.
2020-08-21T15:51:09.2309726Z ...failed updating 12 targets...
2020-08-21T15:51:09.2312270Z ...skipped 52 targets...
2020-08-21T15:51:09.2312837Z ...updated 15703 targets...
2020-08-21T15:51:09.2509339Z C:\install\boost_1_68_0   
2020-08-21T15:51:09.2603988Z 
2020-08-21T15:51:09.2604408Z 
2020-08-21T15:51:09.2818352Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

[Link to actions of my repo with full logs/code](https://github.com/Porok12/networking/actions)

Do you have any tips or advises?

Comment: Please make sure to add computer and windows version (including any patches or updates) as many users will ask for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue that i was facing, was that libraries have -x64 (or x32) in name and therefore find_package was not able to find required libraries (Really helpfull was setting -DBoost_DEBUG=ON).

```
Could NOT find Boost (missing: system) (found version "1.68.0")
```

Setting Boost_ARCHITECTURE to "-x64", does the job

```
set(Boost_ARCHITECTURE "-x64")
```

For Github Actions i also need to use

```
continue-on-error: true # to prevent failing workflow when step exit with errors (when installing boost)
if: success() || failure() # to run following steps even if previous step failed
```

So if you have similar problem

1. Install boost with gcc
2. Make sure that cmake find boost, by checking BOOST_ROOT, BOOST_LIBRARIES
3. If any error, occurs look caerfuly on error message and use Boost_DEBUG

Here is my code:

```
name: build and run tests

on:
  push:
    branches: [ server ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ server ]
    
jobs:
  build-windows:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install PostgreSQL
        run: |
          Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs
          choco install -y postgresql12
      - name: Download Boost
        shell: powershell
        run: |
          $uri = 'https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.68.0/source/boost_1_68_0.zip'
          [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
          Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -OutFile C:\boost.zip -UserAgent [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent]::Chrome
      - name: Unzip boost
        run: Expand-Archive -LiteralPath 'C:\boost.zip' -DestinationPath C:\install\
      - name: Run bootstrap
        shell: powershell
        run: |
          cd C:\install\boost_1_68_0\tools\build\
          .\bootstrap.bat gcc
      - name: Install Boost
        continue-on-error: true
        shell: powershell
        run: |
          cd C:\install\boost_1_68_0\tools\build\
          .\b2 --with-system --with-program_options --with-serialization --with-test --build-type=complete -j2 --prefix="C:\boost-build" toolset=gcc install
          $env:Path += ";C:\boost-build\bin"
          cd C:\install\boost_1_68_0
          C:\boost-build\bin\b2.exe --with-system --with-program_options --with-serialization --with-test --build-type=complete -j2 --build-dir="C:\install\boost_1_68_0\build" --build-type=complete --prefix="C:\boost" toolset=gcc install
      - name: Check libs names
        if: success() || failure()
        run: |
          cd c:\boost\lib
          Get-ChildItem
      - name: Running cmake
        if: success() || failure()
        run: |
          $env:BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = 'C:\boost\include'
          $env:BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = 'C:\boost\lib'
          $env:BOOST_ROOT = 'C:\boost'
          mkdir build
          cd build
          cmake -DBOOST_ROOT=c:/boost -DBoost_DEBUG=ON -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
      - name: Running make (MinGW Makefiles)
        if: success() || failure()
        run: |
          cd build
          make
```

```
set(CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0074 NEW)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(Server VERSION 0.0.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static")

...

if (WIN32)
    # Here i'm setting boost paths based on BOOST_ROOT, you can skip this
    set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS TRUE)
    if (Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS)
      set(BOOST_ROOT "${BOOST_ROOT}")
      message("  > ${BOOST_ROOT}")
      set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "${BOOST_ROOT}/include")
      message("  > ${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR}")
      set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "${BOOST_ROOT}/lib")
      message("  > ${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR}")
    endif (Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS)
    
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   ON)
    set(Boost_ARCHITECTURE "-x64")
endif (WIN32)

find_package(Boost 1.60.0 COMPONENTS REQUIRED program_options serialization system)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(Server ${FILES})

target_link_libraries(Server ${Boost_LIBRARIES} pthread)
```